# Is it possible to import the old project files in the new project?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have two versions installed of UnrealEngine4, **UE_v4.18** and **UE_v4.26**.
I copied asset file **weapon.anim** from the old 4.18 content to new 4.26 content folder,
I have an error in the engine: **weapon.anim is too old**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to start the UE_4.18 version project with UE_4.26, you can then migrate the file to the new project folder. Unreal Engine makes automatically the conversion of files whenever you use a newer version of the editor if it's possible. What you should do is to start the UE_4.26 and then select your old project. When a dialog like this will pop up:

[image: ue4 conversion dialog]

chose to *Open a copy* of it and it will convert it. If you can open it with no errors, select all files you want to migrate and access the migration functionality.

Comment: I have only .uasset files, I copy the whole content folder in the new project and restarted the engine... now it reads some of the assets and some are still "unversioned, too old" and I am not able to open them.

Comment: Did you try to open those uasset in a new project with old version UE?

Comment: yes, and in the logs I got unversioned too old assets.

Comment: Even with the old version of UE4? This never happened to me and I don't know how to help you, I'm sorry.

Comment: I found a third party program and it can convert .uasset to psk file if the .uasset is related to skeletal mesh, and it will convert .uasset to .psa if the .uasset is related to animations.
also founds a way to import .psk and psa in blender and then export as .fbx  and ue4 will  import the fbx and this way I can use my old assets.